# Unstacking Data Frame By Columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to unstack a data frame in R according to two columns, i.e. starting with

```
id   segment  count  freq
1    a        x1a    f1a
1    b        x1b    f1b
1    c        x1c    f1c
2    a        x2a    f2a
2    b        x2b    f2b
2    c        x2c    f2c
```

I want to get:

```
id   count_a  count_b count_c freq_a freq_b freq_c
1    x1a      x1b     x1c     f1a    f1b    f1c
2    x2a      x2b     x2c     f2a    f2b    f2c
```

Basically, this amounts to unstacking the data frame by the first two columns id and segment. However, I don't see how to get this to work using the unstack() function in R. I can do this using a very naive approach (nested for loop, concatenating column names etc and then binding), but there must be a more straightforward and efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%       
   pivot_wider(names_from = c(segment), values_from = c(count, freq))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#     id count_a count_b count_c freq_a freq_b freq_c
#  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1     1 x1a     x1b     x1c     f1a    f1b    f1c   
#2     2 x2a     x2b     x2c     f2a    f2b    f2c
```

---

Or with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), id ~ segment, value.var = c('count', 'freq'))
#   id count_a count_b count_c freq_a freq_b freq_c
#1:  1     x1a     x1b     x1c    f1a    f1b    f1c
#2:  2     x2a     x2b     x2c    f2a    f2b    f2c
```

#### Update

If there are duplicates, then create a sequence column

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(segment)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = c(segment), values_from = c(count, freq)) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

Or with `data.table`

```
dcast(setDT(df1), id + rowid(segment) ~ segment, 
       alue.var = c('count', 'freq'))[, segment := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), segment = c("a", 
"b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), count = c("x1a", "x1b", "x1c", "x2a", 
"x2b", "x2c"), freq = c("f1a", "f1b", "f1c", "f2a", "f2b", "f2c"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that the dcast example assigns a 0 or 1 to every value, so something went wrong. For example, if x1a=12, xa1_segment = 1 after applying dcast

Comment: That one gives me a strange result as well. I still have multiple entries for each id, but with NA values in some of the rows. It does work for the df1 that you specify with the structure function, but not for the data frame that I'm using. Is there something specific to the use of a list (rather than a vector) for the id column that may account for the difference?

Comment: @Max ok, that is the issue.  If you showed an example wiht that duplicates, then it would have been beeter

Comment: I used df1 = read.csv(<filename>) for my df1, then I applied the exact syntax that you used (I'm assuming that the first column of my df1 is not a list). When I apply the dcast syntax, I get a warning that states "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to length". The resulting data table replaces all values with 0 or 1. I'm not sufficiently familiar with dcast to understand what the warning message means, but I assume it explains why I'm getting this strange result.

Comment: @Max If you used the uupdated version, then it should have gone away

Comment: @Max Cany you please `dput`  a small reproducible example so that I can get the structure correctly and your expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214452/discussion-between-max-and-akrun).

Comment: @Max I am in the chat